# Библиотеки криптопро

Tags: java, криптография, криптопро

с криптопро я раньше не работал. Но сейчас в нашей компании возникла задача реанимировать сервис для подписи файлов. В проекте были библиотеки ru.cryptopro.dss.services Где можно их найти? В центральном репозитории мавена их нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это платная библиотека, либо ищите машины, на которых был данный проект развёрнут и берите `jar` оттуда, либо похоже придётся купить снова. Хотя точной информации не представлено, в любом случае вопрос не совсем по адресу, обратитесь к официальному сайту.